# Is $ an operator in C if yes then why?

Tags: c

I got this confusion when I was working on infix to prefix conversion using C
Infix Expression:**A-B+(N$N)*(O+P)+Q/R^S*T+Z**

where I found $ being used as an operator.

So to clear my doubt I made a program performing a$b operation in C to see if it is yielding results like other operators but got to see no answer.
The output further increased my doubt regarding the $ operator and its use in C.

If a=5,b=6 then if we do a+b and print the sum we get 11. In the case of $ if we are considering it as an operator and doing a$b then I am not getting any result. So I was confused that whether $ is an operator or not in the case of C

Comment: It's not a C operator.

Comment: *where I found $ being used as an operarator.* - explain this.

Comment: Please show the full, runnable program that you ran as a test.

Comment: I smell Haskell.

Comment: `I ran a program a$b in C` Was the program name `a$b`, and what does "*ran ... in C*" exactly mean?

Comment: if a=5,b=6 then if we do a+b and print the sum we get 11. In the case of $ if we are considering it as an operator and doing  a$b then I am not getting any result. So I was confused that whether $ is an operator or not in the case of C.

Comment: @JAHNVISRIVASTAVA `a$b` should give you a compiler error if `a`, `b` are variable names, which is a good hint that `$` is not a valid C operator.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers (including [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) accept, **as an *extension* to the C language**, [a `$` inside an identifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html). You may also need support from your [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) and [assembler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

But standard C usually disallow that. Read e.g. [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) to learn more, and also the [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf) draft standard. Check also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website (it seems that `$` are permitted in recent C standards).

IIRC, on [VAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX) computers under [VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS), you did have a lot of system identifiers with a `$`.

I guess you could improve some open source C compiler (not only [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), but also [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), [tinycc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler), [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/)...) to accept `$` as some operator.

My recommendation would be to not use `$` in your identifiers, and to take inspiration from existing open source software (e.g. [GTK](https://gtk.org/)).

For example the following `/tmp/dollar.c` file

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  int doll$ar = 2;
  printf("from %s doll$ar is %d and argc is %d\n", 
         argv[0], doll$ar, argc);
}
```

using [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) on Linux/x86-64 in December 2020 as `gcc -Wall -Wextra /tmp/dollar.c -o /tmp/dollar` compiles without warnings. When I run `/tmp/dollar` the output is:

```
from /tmp/dollar doll$ar is 2 and argc is 1
```

Few open source software (look into the source code of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)) are using `$` in identifiers.

PS. I believe that future standards might allow [UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) letters in identifiers, but you need to check with your [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) representative.

Comment: The C standard has allowed Unicode characters in identifiers since 1999 at least, and it also explicitly allows implementation-defined characters.